# Spanish word derived or borrowed from Portuguese... How would you call it?

Tags: extranjerismos

I know the name given to certain words related to foreign languages:

- "Anglicismo", taken from English (e.g. "troca" for "truck")
- "Galicismo", taken from French ("garage")
- ...

But now I'm wondering: Is there a name given to words taken from Portuguese?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusitanismo) gives 'lusitanismo' and 'portuguesismo' and lists some examples:

> bandeja, biombo, buzo, carambola, caramelo, catre, chubasco, mejillón, mermelada, ostra, sargazo, carabela, almeja, barullo, menina, moho, paria, sarao, vitola

Comment: También [lusismo](https://dle.rae.es/?w=lusismo).

Comment: _Almeja_ is a nice example. One would suspect an Arabic origin like so many Spanish word beginning with _al,_ but no: it probably stems from the Portugese _ameijoa._